# Importing semantic ui into a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I've installed semantic ui via npm. Its currently within **node_modules** and was built into /dist/. Looks like so:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "react": "^15.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "0.0.93",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "semantic-ui": "^2.2.2"
  }
```

And file structure looks like...

```
 /node_modules/
        |- ...
        |- semantic-ui
               |- dist
                    |- components
                    |- themes
                    |- semantic.min.css
                    |- semantic.min.js
```

In my react component **app.jsx**, i'm importing react, react-dom, jquery, but it seems to have an issue with semantic-ui-

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';
import * from 'semantic-ui';


ERROR in ./assets/js/app.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/maude/Projects/coffee/assets/js/app.jsx: Unexpected token (4:9)
  2 | import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  3 | import $ from 'jquery';
> 4 | import * from 'semantic-ui';
```

Why is this import a problem? How can I bring semantic-ui css/js into my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to import an entire module for side effects only, without importing any bindings, then write:

`import 'semantic-ui';`

Otherwise, you will need to name it:

`import * as semantic from 'semantic-ui';`

Although it likely has a default export, so you can just write:

`import semantic from 'semantic-ui';`

**Edit**: Although, for semantic-ui, the import process appears to work a little differently than you might expect. Have a look at [this discussion](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/3533).

Comment: `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'semantic-ui' ` . Module not found despite the fact I'm literally looking right at it lol :\

Comment: Then actually this is an issue with how semantic-ui works. Check out this [thread](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/3533). Looks like you need to import files specifically, as you require them.

Answer (score -2):

Using semantic-ui-css shouldn't give anywhere near as much pain as it's not meant to be hacked (customized). Whereas simply installing semantic-ui will not provide you with the "stuff" instead requiring that you configure webpack, or whatever customizing css framework involves- configuring component at a time and importing that.

within main.js (or where ever react is instantiated) after npm install semantic-ui-css:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
require('semantic-ui-css/semantic.css')
require('semantic-ui-css/semantic.js')
```

Comment: Just clarifying what the tool is intended not for what may be presumed and providing a modified tool as a workaround must qualify more so as an answer than generic response that is merely suitable for concluding that tool at hand isn't generic.